# Is parcelable object passed through bundle same as original one?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, parcelable

This is something that has bothered me for a while now.

If we have some kind of Parcelable object in our activity and we pass it to fragment using Bundle, I've always thought the object that we receive in fragment is actually a new object. However, after running some tests today, it seems the object in fragment is actually same as the object in activity.

Is that correct?

EDIT: Small clarification. I don't refer to object's values. I refer to the '==' comparison.

Comment: Yes, it is. the objects are equal ;)

Comment: Thanks for quick response :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make your object `Parcelable` and then you pass it into another activity using `Intent`,something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("name_of_extra", myParcelableObject);
```

the object you receive in another activity or fragment is the exact object you pass it before.
you can receive the object in this way:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
MyParcelable myParcelableObject = (MyParcelable)i.getParcelableExtra("name_of_extra");
```

Comment: May I know is there any official doc or link can show more explain for this? I recently got a bug and turns out they are the same object, which is quite surprising. (btw I also ask chatGPT for this question and gpt said they are not 

Comment: I think chat gpt is right. I made mistake and they are not the same. you can take a look at 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent